# Just curious: why WPF binding to control's properties not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls

I'm familiar with WPF binding and MVVM. One day when answering questions on [Baidu Zhidao](http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/457609275372058645) I encountered such case:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="lb" DisplayMemberPath="S"/>
</Grid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lb.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item("aa"),
            new Item("bb"),
            new Item("cc"),
        };
    }
}

public class Item : ListBoxItem //
{
    public Item(string s)
    {
        this.S = s;
    }
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

If Item inherits ListBoxItem or other control, then nothing displays.
But why? Isn't **S always a property** of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind `ItemsSource` to data it creates a `ListBoxItem` for each element and displays it using the `DisplayMemberPath` you've specified. However if you bind to an array of `ListBoxItem` that you've created yourself in code-behind then it will use those instead. In the code you posted your `Item` class inherits `ListBoxItem` so it's a GUI element, not data. This is poor practice, but if it's what you actually intend to do then you don't need the `S` property, just set `Content` directly:

```
public class Item : ListBoxItem
{
    public Item(string s)
    {
        this.Content = s;
    }
}
```

But if you want to do it *properly* (e.g. MVVM) then don't inherit `ListBoxItem` and don't manipulate the UI elements directly in code-behind:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string s)
    {
        this.S = s;
    }
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```